# How do I get the named fields in haskell correctly?

Tags: haskell

I am writing a parser with the help of parsec and I have a problem

```
data Param = Param {paramName::String, argument :: Maybe String}
  deriving (Show)

paramExpr1 :: Parser Param
paramExpr1 = do
  paramKeyword
  void $ lexeme $ char '-'
  paramName <- word
  return $ Param paramName Nothing 

paramExpr3 :: Parser Param
paramExpr3 = do
  pN  <- paramExpr1 -- <- PROBLEM HERE
  return $ Param pN Nothing
```

In short, I don't understand how to get the named field, paramExpr1 will return Param and I would like to get paramName, but I don't understand how

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want. Do you want the name, or a parser that, when executed, will produce the name?

Comment: The *parser* does not have a named field, so if the former, `Parser Param` is the wrong type. You either want `Parser String` or `Parser Param -> String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the field by using the field name as a function:

```
paramExpr3 :: Parser Param
paramExpr3 = do
  pN <- paramExpr1
  return $ Param (paramName pN) Nothing
```

Alternatively, instead of creating a new value using the constructor `Param`, you can use the record update syntax and change the fields you want to change while leaving the others as they are.

```
paramExpr3 :: Parser Param
paramExpr3 = do
  pN <- paramExpr1
  return pN{ argument = Nothing }
```

More alternatives exist (e.g. using lenses), but these are the most basic approaches.

Comment: Oh, and I was trying to do something like 

` pN  <- paramExpr1 {f1, f2} `
` return $ Param f1 Nothing `

Comment: You can also try `Param{paramName=f1} <- paramExpr1 ; return $ Param f1 Nothing`. Or `Param{paramName=f1 , argument=f2} <- paramExpr1 ; return $ Param f1 Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

`Parser` is a functor, so you can map a function over a parser to apply the function to whatever the parser will produce.

```
paramExpr3 :: Parser Param
paramExpr3 = do
    pName <- fmap parserName parseExpr1 -- turn a Parser Param into a Parser String
    return $ Param pName Nothing
```

If you had a function of type `Param -> Param` that replaced the existing `argument` field with `Nothing`

```
toNothing :: Param -> Param
toNothing (Param n _) = Param n Nothing
```

you could map that directly over the parsers.

```
parseExpr3 :: Parser Param
parseExpr3 = fmap toNothing parseExpr1
```